# Populate two DataGridViews with different rows from one DataTable

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm trying to populate 2 DataGridViews with records from 1 DataTable with the below code:

```
Public Class Form2
    Public items As DataTable
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        GetData()
    End Sub
    Public Sub GetData()
        Dim dt_existing_rows As New DataTable
        Dim dt_new_rows As New DataTable
        For Each dr As DataRow In items.Rows
            If RunMySqlScalar("SQL Query", My.Settings.ConnectionString) > 0 Then
                dt_existing_rows.ImportRow(dr)
            Else
                dt_new_rows.ImportRow(dr)
            End If
        Next
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt_new_rows
        DataGridView2.DataSource = dt_existing_rows
    End Sub
End Class
```

Issue is that the rows get created but they do not show any data at all within the cells.

[Update - Providing more context for this]

The public `items` DataTable gets populated from a previous form which is a list of all items that are to be added to a SQL table. The reason for splitting the data up via the `For Each` and `If` is to check whether any of the rows within `items` already exist in the destination table. The rows which exist are shown on `DataGridView2` to indicate the user that they will not be re-created or duplicated and ones that will be added are shown in `DataGridView1`.

Comment: Your code makes little sense as it is. At no point do you actually create a `DataTable` and assign it to `items`, let alone populate it. It is also executing a separate query for each row, which seems rather crazy. What you should almost certainly be doing is executing a single query to populate a single `DataTable`, creating two `DataViews` from that table and setting a different `RowFilter` on each one and then binding them to your grids. If you explain what the actual criteria are for separating the rows then we could probably advise what that single query should look like.

Comment: I have provided more context, hopefully that helps @jmcilhinney? In terms of executing SQL query for each row is because each row has to be checked whether it already exists in a destination SQL table. Based on your suggestion with `DataViews` I am wondering whether I should add a boolean column to the `items DataTable` and based on this create the 2 `DataViews` which would be the `DataSource` for both `DataGridViews`.

Comment: That was basically my implication, i.e. you should incorporate that second, row-specific query into the original query. Any extra column(s) it adds to the `DataTable` doesn't have to be mapped to a column in the grids. If the point is to know whether there's a corresponding row in another table, you can do an outer join and take the PK column from the other table and then the filtering would be done on whether or not that column was NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Answering yet another question of mine myself... Based on comments from @jmcilhinney I have changed the code of the GetData() function to the below:

```
Public Sub GetData()
    Dim dt_existing_rows As New DataView(items, "exists = True", "Product", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
    Dim dt_new_rows As New DataView(items, "exists = False", "Product", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)

    DataGridView2.DataSource = dt_existing_rows
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt_new_rows

    DataGridView2.Columns("exists").Visible = False
    DataGridView1.Columns("exists").Visible = False

    DataGridView2.AutoResizeColumns()
    DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns()

End Sub
```

The change that is not visible here is that the `items DataTable` now has a new column `exists` and it holds the data that was previously figured out via the `For Each` loops in the original code. This removed the need of executing a SQL Query for each row within the DataTable.

Again, thanks to @jmcilhinney :)